# Passing a variable in ASP using reponse redirect

Tags: asp-classic

I'm trying to pass a variable using Response.Redirect I have a page that I'm processing the info on which contains:

```
divrec = request.QueryString("div")
divstring = "divisions.asp?"&divrec
Response.Redirect  divstring
```

But when I try to retrieve the information in another page by using

```
<%  divrec = request.QueryString("div")
%>

<% =divrec %>
```

The variable/string does not display

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think you missed the querystring parameter in your `divstring` variable.

Try this:

```
divstring = "divisions.asp?div="&divrec
```

You should be able to access the parameter in the receiving page now.

Comment: Thanks so much! Worked liked a charm!

Comment: if you could mark this as the answer, i'd be most grateful :)

Comment: Ok, Sorry for the delay. Will do!

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is get the parameter from the url.
So if you redirected the user to www.mysite.com/divisions.asp?something
You could parse it up to the ? and get everything after it.

Try looking at http://www.powerasp.net/content/new/get-current-page-url.asp

Also this page might help you out

[how to pass values from one page to other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585901/how-to-pass-values-from-one-page-to-other?rq=1)