# How do I pass a form value to different redirect pages?

Tags: forms, redirect, iis, vbscript, asp-classic

I just developed a platform that prints single ASP documents right after submitting an ID number using the form shown below:

```
<form action="http://localhost/teg/f1.asp" method="POST">
        <input type="number" name="number" placeholder="Please Enter ID" />
        <button type="submit">Print</button>        
</form>
```

In this case it's printing a document called f1.asp. However, I also have f2.asp so instead of writing the form twice for two separate fields I decided to write the form once and include a drop-down list that lets the user choose what to print but for this I guess I needed another page which I called redirect. The form changes look as follows:

```
<form action="http://localhost/teg/redirect.asp" method="POST" id="new">
        <input type="number" name="number" placeholder="Please Enter ID" />
        <button type="submit">Print</button>        
</form>
<label> Type </label>
<select name="list" form="new">
<option value="1">f1</option>
<option value="2">f2</option>  
</select>
```

And the redirect ASP page looks:

```
<html>
<body>
<%            
    Dim list
    list = request.form("list")
If list=1 Then response.redirect("f1.asp") Else If list=2 Then      response.redirect("f2.asp") End If
 %>
```

Finally, when clicking on Print using the drop-down list it redirects perfectly but the value of "number" from the ID number field doesn't reach the document type selected by the user so the document is not displayed properly. Instead, the following Database Engine error appears: '80040e10'. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You lose the `number` form post parameter when you redirect. In the redirect page store the `Request.Form("number")` in a variable then pass that variable to the redirect `Response.Redirect "fi.asp?" & yourvar`. Another approach that could work is `Server.Transfer` which doesn't do a hard redirect and allows you to use the form posted parameters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to pass values from one page to other?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585901/how-to-pass-values-from-one-page-to-other)

Answer (score 2):

It's important to remember that HTTP is stateless it's only through technologies like Cookies that allow Classic ASP to store values in the `Session` object across HTTP requests.

At the moment because of `Response.Redirect()` the value of `Request.Form("number")` is lost when the new request is sent. There are a few ways you can fix this, I'll focus on three here.

#### 1. Pass Value Through Redirect as a QueryString

The easiest method is to pass-through the value you need to make the page you are redirecting to work correctly.

```vb
<%
'Assign our form values to local variables.
Dim list: list = Request.Form("list") & ""
Dim id: id = Request.Form("number") & ""

'Check the value contain data and they are valid numeric values.
If Len(list) > 0 And IsNumeric(list) Then list = CLng(list) Else list = 0
If Len(id) > 0 And IsNumeric(id) Then id = CLng(id) Else id = 0

'***** Only process if we have valid values to build the redirect. *****
Dim url
If list > 0 And id > 0 Then
  'We have valid values build our URL that we will use in
  'the redirect call.
  url = "f" & list & ".asp?id=" & id     
Else
  'Something not right with request go back to the form page.
  'Setting this will send the page back to the form page when the
  'redirect is called.
  url = "formpage.asp"
End If

'Make the redirect request.
Call Response.Redirect(url)
%>
```

Then in the redirected page call the `id` querystring value using `Request.QueryString("id")`.

#### 2. Use `Server.Transfer()` Method

In some case's you can use this method to simplify the code. In simple terms instead of redirecting it "stitches" the requested page to the bottom of the current request allowing the form parameters to still be accessible as technically it is still the same request as far as the Internet Browser is concerned.

```vb
<%
Dim list: list = Request.Form("list") & ""
Dim id: id = Request.Form("number") & ""
If Len(list) > 0 And IsNumeric(list) Then list = CLng(list) Else list = 0
If Len(id) > 0 And IsNumeric(id) Then id = CLng(id) Else id = 0

If list > 0 And id > 0 Then
  Call Server.Transfer("f" & list & ".asp")
Else
  'Handle invalid request here
End If
%>
```

You will be able to use any values from the `Request` object such as `.Form` and `QueryString` in your transferred page without incurring an error because as far as the server is concerned they are still the same page.

#### 3. Store Value in the `Session` Object

If you have `Enable Session State` set to `True` in IIS you can store values across requests inside the `Session` object *(Classic ASP uses a Session Cookie to maintain session state in server memory)*.

```vb
<%
Dim list: list = Request.Form("list") & ""
Dim id: id = Request.Form("number") & ""
If Len(list) > 0 And IsNumeric(list) Then list = CLng(list) Else list = 0
If Len(id) > 0 And IsNumeric(id) Then id = CLng(id) Else id = 0

If list > 0 Then
  'Store the value we want to persist in the Session.
  Session("PrintId") = id
  Call Response.Redirect("f" & list & ".asp")
Else
  'Handle invalid request here.
End If
%>
```

Then to get the value back inside your redirected page use `varname = Session("PrintId")`.

Comment: Thanks! Excellent code. I tried the first method but for some reason the formpage is always being displayed after clicking the button.

Comment: @AlexanderLopez that is because it assumes the value for `list` and `number` are numeric, if not they are set to `0` and don't pass the check `If list > 0 And id > 0 Then`.

Comment: I am actually trying to print one of the documents by entering real ID numbers from Database what I consider the only way the code passes the check. However, is it still possible to be getting the formpage right after data submission?

Comment: @AlexanderLopez if you look at the code I provided yes it is if the value of both `list` and `number` are `0` *(notice the `If` statement `Else` you see it redirects to `formpage.asp`)*. Remove that redirect from the `Else` if you don't want it to do that, but you might pass incorrect data. I'm sanatising the form input to begin with if the values of `Request.Form("list")` and `Request.Form("number")` are not both numeric they get set to `0`, this is then checked before attempting to redirect. I've added some comments to example 1 to try and clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Late in the day but a little bit more simple. Rather than do a redirect, simply populate a new form with the action URL and all data then trigger submit it with JS submit after validated. Downside is JS may be clobbered but then do a catch and, well, alternate option. Reason a late response because I was seeking similar until it dawned upon me that redirect unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Your form is closed too early:

```js
<form action="http://localhost/teg/redirect.asp" method="POST" id="new">
        <input type="number" name="number" placeholder="Please Enter ID" />
        <button type="submit">Print</button>        
</form> <---- THIS
<label> Type </label>
<select name="list" form="new">
<option value="1">f1</option>
<option value="2">f2</option>  
</select>
</form> <---- SHOULD BE HERE
```

The other answers will work; however, this answers your question as to
why "your" code isn't working.